# after typing in a word the cursor jumps to the beginning of that word

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, mark.js

I'm working on a "text-checker" while using Mark.js.

The issue I am having is, that once I input the word and it gets marked/highlighted the cursor jumps to the beginning of that word. Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/p5mxa2s8/).

Maybe the solution would be to somehow save the cursor location before the markup is triggered and loading it once the markup is done? Since I don't know when the markup is triggered maybe, save cursor location on every input and loading again index+1?

Any help, pointers, reference would be welcome.

Thank you

```
<div class="textarea" id="textarea" contenteditable="true">
    I hate blood pudding and so do you.
</div>
```

```
.red { background-color: lightcoral; }

.green{ background-color: lightgreen; }

.brown{ background-color: burlywood; }
```

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
var instance = new Mark("div.textarea");

var red   = ["red", "blood"];
var brown = ["brown", "pudding"];
var green = ["green", "grass"];

var markWords = function() {
    instance.mark(red, {
       seperateWordSearch: false,
       className: "red",
       "accuracy": {
          "value": "exactly",
          "limiters": [",", ".", "!", "?"]
       }
    });

    instance.mark(brown, {
        seperateWordSearch: false,
        className: "brown",
        "accuracy": {
           "value": "exactly",
           "limiters": [",", ".", "!", "?"]
        }
    });
   
     instance.mark(green, {
        seperateWordSearch: false,
        className: "green",
        "accuracy": {
           "value": "exactly",
           "limiters": [",", ".", "!", "?"]
        }
    });
}

markWords();

textarea.addEventListener("input", markWords);
```

A big shout out @mcernak for helping me get to this point.

Comment: Cannot replicate your issue.... Could you explain the steps?

Comment: As I type I only see 300 nested `<mark>`  under the first *"blood"*

Comment: You're not using `markInstance.unmark` even though it's suggested even in their examples:  https://jsfiddle.net/julmot/hdyLpy37/

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the reply. The easiest way would be to go to the (updated) fiddle and type any of the following words into the textarea: *green, red, brown*. You will see that the carot/cursor moves to the beginning of that word. I have updated the fiddle so it includes unmark, but that did not solve the cursor issue.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue as you explained it. The only issue I see: set the cursor inside an already highlighted word - start typing in the middle of it. - Only in such case the caret jumps to the beginning of that word. Not sure if it's a bug on part of Mark.js - not going to investigate that. You could raise a bug report on their git pages maybe? - Or maybe the plugin was not intended to work on live editable elements? Not sure.

Comment: No problem. I was "hoping someone already had this issue" and resolved it. Thank you for taking the time to look into it. I have already raised the issue on their GitHub site.